No changes in dwm when modifing config.h
Hi everyone i reinstalled archcraft with dwm on my laptop with new fresh installation.
The problem occur when i tried to modify the dwm config.h file.
i installed the archcraft-dwm pack from github (like said in the website) and modified /opt/dwm-source/config.h file to set firefox default in the second SchemeTag and floating, but id doesn't work. In fact no changes on config.h works!
i modified the firefox's rules in :
{ "firefox", NULL, NULL, 1<<7, 1, 1, -1 }, 
because my
xprop | awk '
/^WM_CLASS/{sub(/.* =/, "instance:"); sub(/,/, "\nclass:"); print}
/^WM_NAME/{sub(/.* =/, "title:"); print}'xprop | awk '
/^WM_CLASS/{sub(/.* =/, "instance:"); sub(/,/, "\nclass:"); print}
/^WM_NAME/{sub(/.* =/, "title:"); print}'   

print this:
instance: "Navigator"
class: "firefox"
title: "Submit to r/archcraft — Mozilla Firefox"

This before my fresh installation works correctly, but now it seem doesn't work.
I restart my dwm with the command:
MOD+SHIFT+R
but nothing.
I also tried to restart computer, but nothing
any Help??
following the config.h:
/* See LICENSE file for copyright and license details. */
/* Copyright (C) 2020-2024 Aditya Shakya <adi1090x@gmail.com>
 * 
 * DWM Configuration for Archcraft
 * Patched By : siduck76 <https://github.com/siduck76>
 * 
 * */

/* ******************** Configurations ******************** */
static const unsigned int borderpx          = 1;    /* border pixel of windows */
static const unsigned int default_border    = 0;    // to switch back to default border after dynamic border resizing via keybinds
static const unsigned int snap              = 32;   /* snap pixel */
static const unsigned int gappih            = 5;    /* horiz inner gap between windows */
static const unsigned int gappiv            = 5;    /* vert inner gap between windows */
static const unsigned int gappoh            = 5;    /* horiz outer gap between windows and screen edge */
static const unsigned int gappov            = 5;    /* vert outer gap between windows and screen edge */
static                int smartgaps         = 0;    /* 1 means no outer gap when there is only one window */
static const unsigned int systraypinning    = 0;    /* 0: sloppy systray follows selected monitor, >0: pin systray to monitor X */
static const unsigned int systrayspacing    = 10;   /* systray spacing */
static const int systraypinningfailfirst    = 1;    /* 1: if pinning fails,display systray on the 1st monitor,False: display systray on last monitor*/
static const int showsystray                = 1;    /* 0 means no systray */
static const int showbar                    =1; /* 0 means no bar */
enum showtab_modes { showtab_never, showtab_auto, showtab_nmodes, showtab_always };
static const int showtab                    = showtab_auto;
static const int toptab                     = True;
static const int topbar                     = 1;    /* 0 means bottom bar */
static const int horizpadbar                = 15;
static const int vertpadbar                 = 15;
static const int vertpadtab                 = 34;
static const int horizpadtabi               = 10;
static const int horizpadtabo               = 10;
static const int scalepreview               = 4;
static       int tag_preview                = 1;    /* 1 means enable, 0 is off */

/* ******************** Fonts ******************** */
static const char *fonts[]                  = { "JetBrainsMono Nerd Font:size=10" };
static const char dmenufont[]               = "monospace:size=10";
static const int colorfultag                = 1;  /* 0 means use SchemeSel for selected non vacant tag */

/* ******************** Colors ******************** */
#include "colors.h"
static const char *colors[][3]  = {
    /*                     fg      bg      border   */
    [SchemeNorm]       = { gray3,  black,  gray2 },
    [SchemeSel]        = { gray4,  blue,   blue  },
    [TabSel]           = { blue,   gray2,  black  },
    [TabNorm]          = { gray3,  black,  black },
    [SchemeTag]        = { gray3,  black,  black },
    [SchemeTag1]       = { blue,   black,  black },
    [SchemeTag2]       = { red,    black,  black },
    [SchemeTag3]       = { green,  black,  black },
    [SchemeTag4]       = { orange, black,  black },
    [SchemeTag5]       = { purple, black,  black },
    [SchemeTag6]       = { yellow, black,  black },
    [SchemeTag7]       = { pink,   black,  black },
    [SchemeTag8]       = { cyan,   black,  black },
    [SchemeLayout]     = { green,  black,  black }, 
    [SchemeBtnPrev]    = { green,  black,  black }, 
    [SchemeBtnNext]    = { yellow, black,  black }, 
    [SchemeBtnClose]   = { red,    black,  black }, 
};

/* ******************** Tags/Workspaces ******************** */
static char *tags[] = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};

static const int tagschemes[] = { SchemeTag1, SchemeTag2, SchemeTag3,
                                  SchemeTag4, SchemeTag5, SchemeTag6,
                                  SchemeTag7, SchemeTag8
                                };

static const unsigned int ulinepad      = 5;    /* horizontal padding between the underline and tag */
static const unsigned int ulinestroke   = 2;    /* thickness / height of the underline */
static const unsigned int ulinevoffset  = 0;    /* how far above the bottom of the bar the line should appear */
static const int ulineall               = 0;    /* 1 to show underline on all tags, 0 for just the active ones */

/* ******************** Window Rules ******************** */
static const Rule rules[] = {
    /* xprop(1):
     *  WM_CLASS(STRING) = instance, class
     *  WM_NAME(STRING) = title
     */
    /* class                instance    title       tags mask     iscentered   isfloating   monitor */
    { "Gimp",               NULL,       NULL,       0,            0,           1,           -1 },
    { "Inkscape",           NULL,       NULL,       0,            0,           1,           -1 },
    { "firefox",            NULL,       NULL,       1<<7,            1,           1,           -1 },
    { "Viewnior",           NULL,       NULL,       0,            1,           1,           -1 },
    { "MPlayer",            NULL,       NULL,       0,            1,           1,           -1 },
    { "Pcmanfm",            NULL,       NULL,       0,            1,           1,           -1 },
    { "Music",              NULL,       NULL,       0,            1,           1,           -1 },
    { "Yad",                NULL,       NULL,       0,            1,           1,           -1 },
    { "feh",                NULL,       NULL,       0,            1,           1,           -1 },
    { "Pavucontrol",        NULL,       NULL,       0,            1,           1,           -1 },
    { "Lxappearance",       NULL,       NULL,       0,            1,           1,           -1 },
    { "alacritty-float",    NULL,       NULL,       0,            1,           0,           -1 },
    { "VirtualBox Manager",             NULL,       NULL,       0,            1,           1,           -1 },
    { "Nm-connection-editor",           NULL,       NULL,       0,            1,           1,           -1 },
    { "Xfce4-power-manager-settings",   NULL,       NULL,       0,            1,           1,           -1 },
};

/* ******************** Layout(s) ******************** */
static const float mfact            = 0.50;     /* factor of master area size [0.05..0.95] */
static const int nmaster            = 1;        /* number of clients in master area */
static const int resizehints        = 0;        /* 1 means respect size hints in tiled resizals */
static const int lockfullscreen     = 1;        /* 1 will force focus on the fullscreen window */

#define FORCE_VSPLIT 1      /* nrowgrid layout: force two clients to always split vertically */
#include "functions.h"

static const Layout layouts[] = {
    /* symbol     arrange function */
    { "[]=",      tile },    /* first entry is default */
    { "M[]",      monocle },
    { "@[]",      spiral },
    { "/[]",      dwindle },
    { "H[]",      deck },
    { "TTT",      bstack },
    { "===",      bstackhoriz },
    { "HHH",      grid },
    { "###",      nrowgrid },
    { "---",      horizgrid },
    { ":::",      gaplessgrid },
    { "|M|",      centeredmaster },
    { ">M>",      centeredfloatingmaster },
    { "|+|",      tatami },
    { "><>",      NULL },    /* no layout function means floating behavior */
};

/* ******************** Key definitions ******************** */
#define MODKEY Mod4Mask
#define ALTKEY Mod1Mask
#define TAGKEYS(KEY,TAG) \
    { MODKEY,                       KEY,      view,           {.ui = 1 << TAG} }, \
    { MODKEY|ControlMask,           KEY,      toggleview,     {.ui = 1 << TAG} }, \
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             KEY,      tag,            {.ui = 1 << TAG} }, \
    { MODKEY|ControlMask|ShiftMask, KEY,      toggletag,      {.ui = 1 << TAG} },

/* helper for spawning shell commands in the pre dwm-5.0 fashion */
#define SHCMD(cmd) { .v = (const char*[]){ "/bin/sh", "-c", cmd, NULL } }

/* ******************** Commands ******************** */
static char dmenumon[2]                 = "0"; /* component of dmenucmd, manipulated in spawn() */
static const char *dmenucmd[]           = { "dmenu", NULL };

/* Launch Apps */
static const char *stcmd[]              = { "st", NULL };
static const char *termcmd[]            = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_term", NULL };
static const char *floatterm[]          = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_term", "--float", NULL };
static const char *fullterm[]           = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_term", "--full", NULL };
static const char *fmcmd[]              = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_apps", "--file", NULL };
static const char *editcmd[]            = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_apps", "--editor", NULL };
static const char *webcmd[]             = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_apps", "--web", NULL };

/* Rofi Menus */
static const char *rofi_cmd[]           = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/rofi_launcher", NULL };
static const char *rofi_rootcmd[]       = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/rofi_asroot", NULL };
static const char *rofi_layoutcmd[]     = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/rofi_layouts", NULL };
static const char *rofi_mpdcmd[]        = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/rofi_music", NULL };
static const char *rofi_nmcmd[]         = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/network_menu", NULL };
static const char *rofi_powercmd[]      = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/rofi_powermenu", NULL };
static const char *rofi_shotcmd[]       = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/rofi_screenshot", NULL };
static const char *rofi_wincmd[]        = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/rofi_windows", NULL };
static const char *rofi_bluecmd[]       = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/rofi_bluetooth", NULL };
static const char *rofi_runcmd[]        = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/rofi_runner", NULL };

/* Misc */
static const char *cpickcmd[]           = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_colorpicker", NULL };
static const char *musicmd[]            = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_music", NULL };
static const char *lockcmd[]            = { "betterlockscreen", "--lock", NULL };
static const char *layoutswitcher[]     = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_layouts", NULL };

/* Hardware keys for volume and brightness */
#include <X11/XF86keysym.h>
static const char *mutevol[]            = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_volume", "--toggle",  NULL };
static const char *mutemic[]            = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_volume", "--toggle-mic",  NULL };
static const char *upvol[]              = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_volume", "--inc",     NULL };
static const char *downvol[]            = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_volume", "--dec",     NULL };
static const char *upbl[]               = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_brightness", "--inc",    NULL };
static const char *downbl[]             = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_brightness", "--dec",  NULL };

/* Screenshot */
static const char *shotnow[]            = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_screenshot", "--now", NULL };
static const char *shotin5[]            = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_screenshot", "--in5", NULL };
static const char *shotin10[]           = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_screenshot", "--in10", NULL };
static const char *shotwin[]            = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_screenshot", "--win", NULL };
static const char *shotarea[]           = { "/usr/share/archcraft/dwm/scripts/dwm_screenshot", "--area", NULL };

/* ******************** Keybindings ******************** */
static Key keys[] = {
    /* modifier                 key                         function        argument */

    // Hardware Keys -----------
    { 0,                        XF86XK_AudioMute,           spawn, {.v = mutevol } },
    { 0,                        XF86XK_AudioMicMute,        spawn, {.v = mutemic } },
    { 0,                        XF86XK_AudioLowerVolume,    spawn, {.v = downvol } },
    { 0,                        XF86XK_AudioRaiseVolume,    spawn, {.v = upvol   } },
    { 0,                        XF86XK_MonBrightnessUp,     spawn, {.v = upbl   } },
    { 0,                        XF86XK_MonBrightnessDown,   spawn, {.v = downbl   } },

    // Print Keys -----------
    { 0,                        XK_Print,                   spawn, {.v = shotnow } },
    { ALTKEY,                   XK_Print,                   spawn, {.v = shotin5 } },
    { ShiftMask,                XK_Print,                   spawn, {.v = shotin10 } },
    { ControlMask,              XK_Print,                   spawn, {.v = shotwin } },
    { MODKEY,                   XK_Print,                   spawn, {.v = shotarea } },

    // Terminals -----------
    { MODKEY,                   XK_Return,                  spawn, {.v = stcmd } },
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_Return,                  spawn, {.v = floatterm } },
    { MODKEY|ControlMask,       XK_Return,                  spawn, {.v = termcmd } },
    { MODKEY|ALTKEY,            XK_Return,                  spawn, {.v = fullterm } },

    // Launch Apps -----------
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_f,                       spawn, {.v = fmcmd } },
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_e,                       spawn, {.v = editcmd } },
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_w,                       spawn, {.v = webcmd } },
    
    // Rofi Menus -----------
    { ALTKEY,                   XK_F1,                      spawn, {.v = rofi_cmd } },
    { ALTKEY,                   XK_F2,                      spawn, {.v = rofi_runcmd } },
    { MODKEY,                   XK_m,                       spawn, {.v = rofi_mpdcmd } },
    { MODKEY,                   XK_n,                       spawn, {.v = rofi_nmcmd } },
    { MODKEY,                   XK_b,                       spawn, {.v = rofi_bluecmd } },
    { MODKEY,                   XK_r,                       spawn, {.v = rofi_rootcmd } },
    { MODKEY,                   XK_x,                       spawn, {.v = rofi_powercmd } },
    { MODKEY,                   XK_s,                       spawn, {.v = rofi_shotcmd } },
    { MODKEY,                   XK_w,                       spawn, {.v = rofi_wincmd } },

    // Misc -----------
    { MODKEY,                   XK_p,                       spawn, {.v = cpickcmd } },
    { ALTKEY|ControlMask,       XK_l,                       spawn, {.v = lockcmd } },
    { ALTKEY|ControlMask,       XK_m,                       spawn, {.v = musicmd } },

    // Tags -----------
    TAGKEYS(                    XK_1,                       0)
    TAGKEYS(                    XK_2,                       1)
    TAGKEYS(                    XK_3,                       2)
    TAGKEYS(                    XK_4,                       3)
    TAGKEYS(                    XK_5,                       4)
    TAGKEYS(                    XK_6,                       5)
    TAGKEYS(                    XK_7,                       6)
    TAGKEYS(                    XK_8,                       7)
    TAGKEYS(                    XK_9,                       8)

    // DWM Session  -----------
    { MODKEY|ControlMask,       XK_q,                       quit, {0} }, // Quit DWM
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_r,                       quit, {1} }, // Restart DWM

    // Border and Gaps -----------
    /* Borders */
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_equal,                   setborderpx, {.i = +1 } }, // Increase border width
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_minus,                   setborderpx, {.i = -1 } }, // Decrease border width
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_BackSpace,               setborderpx, {.i = default_border } },

    /* Gaps */
    // overall gaps
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_bracketleft,             incrgaps, {.i = +1 } },
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_bracketright,            incrgaps, {.i = -1 } },
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_backslash,               defaultgaps, {0} }, // Default gaps
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_g,                       togglegaps, {0} }, // Toggle gaps

    // inner gaps
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,                 XK_i,               incrigaps, {.i = +1 } },
    { MODKEY|ControlMask|ShiftMask,     XK_i,               incrigaps, {.i = -1 } },

    // outer gaps
    { MODKEY|ControlMask,               XK_o,               incrogaps, {.i = +1 } },
    { MODKEY|ControlMask|ShiftMask,     XK_o,               incrogaps, {.i = -1 } },
    
    // Window Management -----------
    /* Murder */
    { MODKEY,                   XK_c,                       killclient, {0} }, // Kill window
    { MODKEY,                   XK_Escape,                  spawn, SHCMD("xkill") }, // xkill

    /* Switch */
    { MODKEY,                   XK_j,                       focusstack, {.i = +1 } }, // Cycle window
    { MODKEY,                   XK_k,                       focusstack, {.i = -1 } },
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_j,                       movestack, {.i = +1 } }, // Switch master
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_k,                       movestack, {.i = -1 } },

    { MODKEY,                   XK_Left,                    focusstack, {.i = +1 } }, // Cycle window
    { MODKEY,                   XK_Right,                   focusstack, {.i = -1 } },
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_Left,                    movestack, {.i = +1 } }, // Switch master
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_Right,                   movestack, {.i = -1 } },

    { MODKEY,                   XK_i,                       incnmaster, {.i = +1 } }, // Verticle
    { MODKEY,                   XK_u,                       incnmaster, {.i = -1 } }, // Horizontal

    /* Resize */
    { MODKEY,                   XK_h,                       setmfact, {.f = -0.05} }, // Shrink left 
    { MODKEY,                   XK_l,                       setmfact, {.f = +0.05} }, // Shrink right

    { MODKEY|ControlMask,       XK_Left,                    setmfact, {.f = -0.05} }, // Shrink left 
    { MODKEY|ControlMask,       XK_Right,                   setmfact, {.f = +0.05} }, // Shrink right

    /* Misc */
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_b,                       togglebar, {0} }, // Toggle bar
    { MODKEY,                   XK_Tab,                     zoom, {0} }, // Switch to master
    { ALTKEY,                   XK_Tab,                     view, {0} }, // Switch to last tag
    { MODKEY,                   XK_d,                       hidewin, {0} }, // Hide window
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_d,                       restorewin, {0} }, // Restore window
    { MODKEY,                   XK_0,                       view, {.ui = ~0 } },
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_0,                       tag, {.ui = ~0 } },

    // Layouts -----------
    { ALTKEY|ControlMask,       XK_space,                   spawn, {.v = rofi_layoutcmd } },

    { MODKEY|ControlMask,       XK_comma,                   cyclelayout, {.i = -1 } },
    { MODKEY|ControlMask,       XK_period,                  cyclelayout, {.i = +1 } },
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_space,                   togglefloating, {0} },
    { MODKEY,                   XK_f,                       togglefullscr, {0} },

    { MODKEY,                   XK_space,                   setlayout, {0} }, 
    { MODKEY,                   XK_t,                       setlayout, {.v = &layouts[0]} }, // Tile
    { MODKEY,                   XK_g,                       setlayout, {.v = &layouts[10]} }, // Grid
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_m,                       setlayout, {.v = &layouts[1]} }, // Monocle
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_s,                       setlayout, {.v = &layouts[2]} }, // Spiral
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_t,                       setlayout, {.v = &layouts[5]} }, // Stack
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_c,                       setlayout, {.v = &layouts[11]} }, // Centered master
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,         XK_x,                       setlayout, {.v = &layouts[13]} }, // Tatami
    
};

/* ******************** Button definitions ******************** */
/* click can be ClkTagBar, ClkLtSymbol, ClkStatusText, ClkWinTitle, ClkClientWin, or ClkRootWin */
static Button buttons[] = {
    /* click                event mask      button          function        argument */
    { ClkLtSymbol,          0,              Button1,        setlayout,      {0} },
    { ClkLtSymbol,          0,              Button3,        spawn,          {.v = rofi_layoutcmd } },
    { ClkWinTitle,          0,              Button2,        zoom,           {0} },
    { ClkStatusText,        0,              Button2,        spawn,          {.v = termcmd } },

    { ClkClientWin,         MODKEY,         Button1,        moveorplace,    {.i = 0} },
    { ClkClientWin,         MODKEY,         Button2,        togglefloating, {0} },
    { ClkClientWin,         MODKEY,         Button3,        resizemouse,    {0} },
    { ClkTagBar,            0,              Button1,        view,           {0} },
    { ClkTagBar,            0,              Button3,        toggleview,     {0} },
    { ClkTagBar,            MODKEY,         Button1,        tag,            {0} },
    { ClkTagBar,            MODKEY,         Button3,        toggletag,      {0} },
    { ClkTabBar,            0,              Button1,        focuswin,       {0} },
    { ClkTabBar,            0,              Button1,        focuswin,       {0} },
    { ClkTabPrev,           0,              Button1,        movestack,      { .i = -1 } },
    { ClkTabNext,           0,              Button1,        movestack,      { .i = +1 } },
    { ClkTabClose,          0,              Button1,        killclient,     {0} },
};

/* ******************** DWMC ******************** */
void
setlayoutex(const Arg *arg)
{
    setlayout(&((Arg) { .v = &layouts[arg->i] }));
}

void
viewex(const Arg *arg)
{
    view(&((Arg) { .ui = 1 << arg->ui }));
}

void
viewall(const Arg *arg)
{
    view(&((Arg){.ui = ~0}));
}

void
toggleviewex(const Arg *arg)
{
    toggleview(&((Arg) { .ui = 1 << arg->ui }));
}

void
tagex(const Arg *arg)
{
    tag(&((Arg) { .ui = 1 << arg->ui }));
}

void
toggletagex(const Arg *arg)
{
    toggletag(&((Arg) { .ui = 1 << arg->ui }));
}

void
tagall(const Arg *arg)
{
    tag(&((Arg){.ui = ~0}));
}

/* signal definitions */
/* signum must be greater than 0 */
/* trigger signals using `xsetroot -name "fsignal:<signame> [<type> <value>]"` */
static Signal signals[] = {
    /* signum           function */
    { "focusstack",     focusstack },
    { "setmfact",       setmfact },
    { "togglebar",      togglebar },
    { "incnmaster",     incnmaster },
    { "togglefloating", togglefloating },
    { "focusmon",       focusmon },
    { "tagmon",         tagmon },
    { "zoom",           zoom },
    { "view",           view },
    { "viewall",        viewall },
    { "viewex",         viewex },
    { "toggleview",     view },
    { "toggleviewex",   toggleviewex },
    { "tag",            tag },
    { "tagall",         tagall },
    { "tagex",          tagex },
    { "toggletag",      tag },
    { "toggletagex",    toggletagex },
    { "killclient",     killclient },
    { "quit",           quit },
    { "setlayout",      setlayout },
    { "setlayoutex",    setlayoutex },
};


